# System.Net.Mail.MailAddress validates email missing TLD, considers me@there valid

Tags: c#

Considers me@there valid. Is not a TLD required?

```
try
{
    foreach (var email in addresses)
    {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return "Invalid email address";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the spec

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt

It's indeed valid.

Answer (score 1):

> Is not a TLD required?

No.

See, just because THE INTERNET does it so, oes not mean I can not work with direct host names in my own network. Expecially given that default DNS domain (added from the IP settings) may "remap" @there into @there.local transparently ;)